# Monte Carlo Algorithm for binary trees don't start rightly

Tags: python-3.x, montecarlo, monte-carlo-tree-search

I tried to apply the Monte Carlo algorithm to binary trees, but I have the impression that there is an error in the algorithm because it returns my default value.

Here is the structure of the tree in a graphic way:

```
           10
         /    \
        6      14
       / \    /  \
      5   8  11  18
```

You can find the code on GitHub but here is it :

```
# Attempt to apply a Nested Monte Carlo Algorithm to binary trees

from random import *
import numpy as np

MaxPlayoutLength = 20 # what ?

# Class for construct the nodes of the tree. (Subtrees)
class Node:
    def __init__(self, key, parent_node = None):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.key = key
        if parent_node == None:
            self.parent = self
        else:
            self.parent = parent_node

# Class with the  structure of the tree. 
# I'm not sure if this Tree is balanced.
class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    # Insert a single element
    def insert(self, x):
        if(self.root == None):
            self.root = Node(x)
        else:
            self._insert(x, self.root)

    # place it at the right palce
    def _insert(self, x, node):
        if(x < node.key):
            if(node.left == None):
                node.left = Node(x, node)
            else:
                self._insert(x, node.left)
        else:
            if(node.right == None):
                node.right = Node(x, node)
            else:
                self._insert(x, node.right)

    # Given a element, return a node in the tree with key x. 
    def find(self, x):
        if(self.root == None):
            return None
        else:
            return self._find(x, self.root)

    def _find(self, x, node):
        if(x == node.key):
            return node
        elif(x < node.key):
            if(node.left == None):
                return None
            else:
                return self._find(x, node.left)
        elif(x > node.key):
            if(node.right == None):
                return None
            else:
                return self._find(x, node.right)

    # Given a node, return the node in the tree with the next largest element.
    def next(self, node):
        if node.right != None:
            return self._left_descendant(node.right)
        else:
            return self._right_ancestor(node)

    def _left_descendant(self, node):
        if node.left == None:
            return node
        else:
            return self._left_descendant(node.left)

    def _right_ancestor(self, node):
        if node.key <= node.parent.key:
            return node.parent
        else:
            return self._right_ancestor(node.parent)

    # Delete an element of the tree
    def delete(self, x):
        node = self.find(x)
        if node == None:
            print(x, "isn't in the tree")
        else:
            if node.right == None:
                if node.left == None:
                    if node.key < node.parent.key:
                        node.parent.left = None
                        del node # Clean garbage
                    else:
                        node.parent.right = None
                        del Node # Clean garbage
                else:
                    node.key = node.left.key
                    node.left = None
            else:
                x = self.next(node)
                node.key = x.key
                x = None

# a tree with a selected node at a given time
class Board:
    '''a Board is a tree with a node selected which gives a score'''
    def __init__(self, btree, node):
        self.root = node
        self.root.left = node.left
        self.root.right = node.right

        # length = NULL; //TO-DO : number of nodes which have leaves BUT how to count them ?

        moves = np.zeros(2) 
        if(node.left != None):
            self.moves[0] = node.left #/DONE? array of the left and right positions from current state  //node *left; and node *right;
            self.moves[1] = node.right
            score = node.key

    def legalMoves(self, moves):
        if(moves != None):
            return 2
        else:
            return 0

    def terminal(self):
        if(self.root.left == None):
            print("board terminal")
            print(self.root.left)
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def score(self):
        return node.key

    def getLegalMoves(self,node):
        if(node.left != None):
            self.moves[0] = node.left
            self.moves[1] = node.right
            return moves

        # length = NULL; //TO-DO : number of nodes which have leaves BUT how to count them ?

def playout(board):
    moves[2] # shoudln't we get them from the board ?
    while(True):
        nb = board.legalMoves(self.moves)
        if((nb == 0) or board.terminal()):
            return board.score()
        n = random.randint(0, nb) # chose a number between 0 and the number of legal moves
        board.play(moves[n]) # play a random move
        if(board.length >= MaxPlayoutLength -20):
            return 0

bestScoreNested = -9999
DBL_MAX = -9999

arraySize = 10

lengthBestRollout = np.zeros(10) # array of size 10
scoreBestRollout = np.zeros(10) # array of size 10

bestRollout =np.zeros((10,MaxPlayoutLength)) # 2 dimensional array of size 10*MaxPlayoutLength

def nested(board, n):
    '''Nested Monte Carlo algorithm
    a general name for a broad class of algorithms that use random sampling to obtain numerical results.
    It is used to solve statistical problems by simulation.'''

    nbMoves = 0
    moves = np.zeros(2)

    lengthBestRollout[n] -1
    scoreBestRollout[n] - DBL_MAX
    res = -DBL_MAX
    while(True):
        # if it's over we've reached the bottom of the tree
        if(board.terminal()):
            return 0.0
        nbMoves = board.legalMoves(moves) # moves is empty here
        # otherwise
        for i in range(0,nbMoves):
            b = board
            b.play(moves[i])
            if(n==1):
                playout(board)
            else:
                nested (board, n-1)
                score = board.score()
            if(score > scoreBestRollout [n]):
                scoreBestRollout [n] = score
                lengthBestRollout [n] = board.length
                for k in range(0,board.length):
                    bestRollout[n][k]=board.rollout[k]
                if(n>3):
                    for i in range(0,t<n-1):
                        print("n =", n,"progress =", board.length, "score =", scoreBestRollout [n])
                        depth = 0
                        # board.print(stderr) # what 
                        print("")
                        bestBoard = board
                if ((n > 1) and (score > bestScoreNested)):
                    bestScoreNested = score
                    print("best score = ", score)
                    print("")
                    bestBoard = board
        board.play(bestRollout[n][board.length])
    return 0.0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # tests
    t = Tree()
    t.insert(5)
    t.insert(6)
    t.insert(8)
    t.insert(10)
    t.insert(11)
    t.insert(14)
    t.insert(18)

    b = Board(t,Node(5))

    score = nested(b,3)
    print("the algorithm score is ",score)

    # Remember: Find method return the node object. 
    # To return a number use t.find(nº).key
    # But it will cause an error if the number is not in the tree.
```

The problem is that when I try to run this code it gives me back :

```
$ python3 main.py 
board terminal
None
the algorithm score is  0.0
```

Which means that it didn't started out rightly : from the beginning we went right through the terminal state without being able to launch a first node.

```
    # if it's over we've reached the bottom of the tree
    if(board.terminal()):
        return 0.0
    nbMoves = board.legalMoves(moves)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you abbreviated your code in some way, but there seems to be a bunch of stuff missing or just completely nonsensical in what you've shown. For instance, you never set `moves` as an attribute on `board`, so either gets discarded immediately (and all the other places that reference it won't work), or there's some existing global in your namespace also named `moves`. Also, there doesn't appear to be a `Board.move` method, but you have code that calls in in several places.

Comment: @Blckknght Yes, I only set a `node` because I thought it was sufficient ? As nodes are all linked one with the other I thought it was sufficient to the `moves` from the `node` attributed

Comment: @Blckknght, I took your remark about `moves` into account but still don't find out `Board.move` calls